# Chat application for Android using Firebase but without storing data in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, chat

We are developing one application using google classroom APIs where we are building relationship between teacher and student.

Now, we need to add another feature which is basically one to one chat communication between Teacher and student. For this, I was thinking for XMPP or FCM. We have our own server implementation where users(Teachers and students) data are already present and maintained.

But I have few questions on this:

1. If I am going to use FCM based chat, do I need to authenticate the user against FCM? I am already using FCM for notification sending purpose.
2. In some tutorials I have seen that, they are storing the conversations and user data in FCM database. Can I store them in my backend database without storing in FCM database.
3. If i try with XMPP, I am getting many client side code and I can use smack API. But I am not understanding about the server side implementation. Is there any good tutorial or github link present?

P.S. I am not going to use any existing chat sdk which has a pricing model. So, I need the suggestion based on the above.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Comment: You seem to be confused about Firebase Messaging and the Firebase DB.  They aren't the same thing, despite using the same name.  In fact they have nothing to do with one another.  Firebase is just the marketing name for a set of cloud tools Google wrote/bought.

Comment: Not really. If you see codelab tutorial, they are saying to store in firebase db. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#5 . Do you know any good tutorial where I don't need to store in Firebase DB and my own authentication will work.

Comment: Great, so one particular tutorial decided to use two different technologies together.  That doesn't mean you have to.  They are two totally separate and unrelated things-  you can use either without the other if you wish.

Comment: Ok. But again, do we need to authenticate against Firebase? I am already authenticating him using google auth for classroom.

Comment: Another question. how can we store those chat messages? can i store in our backend server?

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebase Cloud Messaging does not require a user to be authenticated. The application instance (the installation of your specific app on a specific device) is identified by an Application ID/FCM token, which is all that FCM needs to deliver messages to that app instance.
2. As Gabe commented, Firebase Cloud Message and the Firebase databases are completely separate products. They can be used together, but don't have to be. Firebase Cloud Messages is not a database, and does example not have an API to query messages that you can call from your app.

Comment: Ok. Understood. But for a FCM based chat application, don't we need to be authenticated? As i said earlier, I am using FCM for sending notifications. And there, we are using FCM token. But I am confused for the chat app. Is there a pretty good article/tutorial present?

Comment: "Firebase Cloud Messaging does not require a user to be authenticated."
Asking for tutorials (and other off-site resources) is off topic on Stack Overflow. That said, I wrote this a few years ago: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html